# Save 2d array of custom object onSaveInstanceState

Tags: android, arrays, bundle, parcelable

Hi im trying to save a 2d array of a custom object in a Bundle inside the method onSaveInstanceState so it saves the array of custom objects when the users rotates the screen
but i dont know how to achieve it.. If possible id like an "easy" solution... Thanks

This is the class of the custom object, i tried to add the implements Parcelable & methods but not sure if that part is correct:

```
package com.example.game
import android.os.Parcel;
import android.os.Parcelable;
//hacemos el implements parcelable para que se puede guardar en el savedinstance
public class NumeroCarton implements Parcelable  {
    protected int numero;
    protected boolean numacertado;
    public NumeroCarton(int numero) {
        this.numacertado =false;
        this.numero = numero;
    }



    public int getNumero() {
        return numero;
    }
    public void setNumero(int numero) {
        this.numero = numero;
    }
    public boolean isNumacertado() {
        return numacertado;
    }
    public void setNumacertado(boolean numacertado) {
        this.numacertado = numacertado;
    }


    ////parcelable  :

    private NumeroCarton(Parcel in) {
        numero = in.readInt();
    }

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }
    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel out, int flags) {
        out.writeInt(numero);

    }

       public static final Parcelable.Creator<NumeroCarton> CREATOR
       = new Parcelable.Creator<NumeroCarton>() {
   public NumeroCarton createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
       return new NumeroCarton(in);
   }

   public NumeroCarton[] newArray(int size) {
       return new NumeroCarton[size];
   }
};
}
```

Ok, Inside the activity where i have the object i want to save,  its micarton, a 2d array
of the class i wrote above :

```
NumeroCarton[][] micarton=new NumeroCarton[5][3];
```

And i want to save it inside the bundle of the onSaveInstanceState method:

```
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outInstance) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outInstance);
        outInstance.putInt(STATE_PUNTOS, puntos);


//This is my problem: 
outInstance.putParcelable(STATE_MICARTONN, micarton);

       //The method putParcelable(String, Parcelable)
// in the type Bundle is not  //applicable for the arguments 
//(String, NumeroCarton[][])
//Neither outInstance.putParcelableArray[](STATE_MICARTONN, micarton)

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think if you make the custom class serializable it will work.

Comment: Hmm tried adding this to the custom class, no success.  I added the implemente Serializable and private static final long serialVersionUID

Comment: public class NumeroCarton implements Parcelable ,Serializable {
 private static final long serialVersionUID = -3644984878389115644L;

Comment: `outInstance.putSerializable(STATE_MICARTONN, micarton);` and `micarton=(NumeroCarton[][]) savedInstanceState.getSerializable(STATE_MICARTONN);` did it  after adding the serialization Thank you !!

Answer (score 0):

There is another easy solution, try to convert 2nd array into csv string like this:

```
data11,data12,data13
data21,data22,data23
....
```

in this format, you can easily convert 2nd array to a string and backwards

Comment: Thanks interesting, but i would have to go through the array and on each [][].getInt write as string and for the [][] boolean make an if statement if true write true on the string, if false write false  if i understood correctly you meant converting the 2d array into a string

Comment: that is what I mean, but if statement is not neened, when you append it to a string buffer, ture or false will be added automaticly. NOTE, this is a simple but not efficiant way